# Insert/Delete/Update inside a dynamic table name in mvc using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a JsonResult code for each Insert/Update/Delete like below in my Controller. Now I want to ask is it possible if I will pass the Id and TableName to Update and Delete from the TableName passed. Also can I write an Insert Query in this way?

So My JsonResult is like this:-

```
public JsonResult DeleteFromTable()
    {
        int IDtoDelete = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["itemId"]);
        string MyTableName = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["TblName"]);

        try
        {

            Type tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
            switch (MyTableName)
            {
                case "CourseTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseTbl);
                    break;
                case "CourseDescTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                    break;
                case "CourseSubDesc":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseSubDesc);
                    break;
                case "InternTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(InternShip);
                    break;
                case "ContactTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(Contact);
                    break;
            }

            using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
            {
                // Want To Add Insert/Update/Delete Code here.


                return new JsonResult { Data = results, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            return new JsonResult { Data = "Not Found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

What I cannot figure out is how to write an EF query for the Insert/Update/Delete. Please HELP!!

Comment: Not sure but I believe you can say db.DbSet(tableName)

Comment: Can you please provide me an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have this approach for your case: First I create a generic class like :

```
    internal class UtilityMethods<TEntity, Tid> where TEntity : class
    {
      public static bool InsertEntity(Entities dbContext, TEntity entity)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then I use this static method based on class I am dealing like:

```
case "CourseTbl":
    results = UtilityMethods<CourseTbl, int>.InsertEntity(dbContext, myObject);
break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell how to pass 'myObject' of that class?

Comment: In the code above `myObject` is an instance object of `CourseTbl` which you want to insert in database.

Comment: Ok I got it. But can you provide me with example of delete?

Comment: Just create another static method inside `internal class UtilityMethods<TEntity, Tid> where TEntity : class` for delete. It will eactly like insert but with 'dbContext.Entry(ent).State = EntityState.Deleted;'

Comment: Actually I want to ask how can I pass the ID which I want to delete for that table.